# Would gagging fall within the scope of Indian Penal Code (IPC) section 375?

Tags: india, interpretation, indian-penal-code, rape

- List item

IPC [section 375](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&sectionId=46151&sectionno=375&orderno=424) states

> A man is said to commit "rape" if he--
>
> (a) penetrates his penis, to any extent, into the vagina, mouth, urethra or anus of a woman or makes her to do so with him or any other person; or
>
> (b) inserts, to any extent, any object or a part of the body, not being the penis, into the vagina, the urethra or anus of a woman or makes her to do so with him or any other person; or
>
> (c) manipulates any part of the body of a woman so as to cause penetration into the vagina, urethra, anus or any part of body of such woman or makes her to do so with him or any other person; or
>
> (d) applies his mouth to the vagina, anus, urethra of a woman or makes her to do so with him or any other person,

> under the following conditions

> First.Against her will.
> Secondly.Without her consent.

> Thirdly.With her consent, when her consent has been obtained by putting her or any person in whom she is interested, in fear of death or of hurt.

> Fourthly.With her consent, when the man knows that he is not her husband and that her consent is given because she believes that he is another man to whom she is or believes herself to be lawfully married.

> Fifthly.With her consent when, at the time of giving such consent, by reason of unsoundness of mind or intoxication or the administration by him personally or through another of any stupefying or unwholesome substance, she is unable to understand the nature and consequences of that to which she gives consent.

> Sixthly.With or without her consent, when she is under eighteen years of age.

> Seventhly.When she is unable to communicate consent.

specifically section (c)

If a woman is shouting and the man uses his hand to cover her mouth tightly so as to cause part of the skin or nerve of his hand to go into the woman's mouth. would that fall within the meaning of rape?

edit;; relevant case law https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thehindu.com/news/national/kerala/hc-expands-definition-of-rape-in-ipc/article35732800.ece/amp/

Comment: why did you delete the earlier question ?

Comment: because the law didn't have the words "into her/his mouth" and I misread it

Comment: actually it still did fit into the definition of the afformentioned text @OldAccount2005

Comment: What part of the definition you provided confuses you?  Section (a) is the only section that mentions the woman's mouth, and it excludes the hand.

Comment: section C @MichaelHall

Comment: Where in section (c) does it mention the man's hand going into the woman's mouth?

Comment: "manipulating ANY part of the body , so as to cause penetration into the vagina , uterus , anus or ANY PART of the body"

Comment: You left out a key phrase that changes the meaning:  "of the woman".  Now that I read it though, if he put her hand in his mouth it would be rape.  By that incredibly poorly worded definition...

Answer (score 0):

No, not according to the very detailed and graphic examples in the definitions you provided in the question.  Nothing in any of those sections describes the man putting his hand inside the woman's mouth, and therefore it would not be considered rape.

Comment: in the comments you said that it would be rape , is that true ? (I hope not) also are you talking about my example or the sections I quoted

Comment: also in all those sections "of the woman" is present but still would even with sexual intent , this fall under the definition of rape according to the section ?

Comment: @IndianLawDropout, No, that isn't what I said in the comments.  Per the wording in section (c):  Man's hand in woman's mouth is not rape, man forcing woman's hand into his (or any other person's) mouth is rape.  I have no idea what you are trying to say in the second comment.